# Почему при первом наведении мыши overlay отображается не на картинке, при наведении еще раз - все ок?

Tags: css, css3, вёрстка

Почему при первом наведении мыши overlay отображается не на картинке:

[image]

при наведении еще раз - все ок?

[image]

Код CSS:

```
#top .grid-entry .image-overlay {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .90)!important;
}

.grid-entry a:hover:before{
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 1;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    animation: avia-fadein 0.75s 1 cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275) !important;
}
```

Посмотреть можно по адресу israel-escorts.com

Comment: А я думаю, почему ваши вопросы часто смотрят, вот оно что:D (offtop)

Comment: А это кстати не нарушение правил SO на русском?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ссылка изначально inline елемент. Скорее всего из за этого плагин не может правильно просчитать высоту и положение для overlay. Поэтому только после того как ссылка получает `display: block` после первого наведения, плагин может корректно отработать второй раз.
Добавьте для `grid-image` `display: block` и для `image-overlay` `top: 0; left: 0;`.